# Source Code and build the binaries for JSON and visual studio using Cmake? for RPG penguinprogrammer tutorial?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I'm trying the c++ RPG tutorial on http://www.penguinprogrammer.co.uk/rpg-tutorial/introduction/. I'm very new to programming, as in I know the basics of C++.

It's almost comical how fast I hit a complete obstacle.

The tutorial says I need to install Cmake to use JSON files in order to store data in the game.

I installed Cmake, and as it instructs I brought up the GUI. It asks "Where is the source code:" and "Where to build the binaries:". I have absolutely no idea what this means :(
Is the source code the JSON files?
I'm trying to do this in visual studio.
https://cmake.org/runningcmake/

If anything, where can I learn just what the heck is going on?

Thanks

Comment: The source will be the root folder containing the CMakelist.txt file. The build folder is where you want the project built. With CMake these are usually different since CMake is designed for out of source building. With this said you most likely shouldn't be doing this yet. CMake was not designed for your experience level.

Comment: I had a typo in the previous comment. The file should be CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it